# revtex4-1 and colortbl doesn't fill cells

Tags: tables, color, revtex, colortbl

The MWE below shows that the `\cellcolor` command doesn't properly fill a table cell in `revtex4-1` where it would do so in a simple `article`. Can anyone help me get fills that extend to the boundaries of my cells in `revtex4-1`?

[image: Difference between article and revtex colortbl]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|l|l| } \hline
\rowcolor{red} A    & B     & C     \\ \hline
Hello World         & other     & \cellcolor{blue}stuff\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

revtex inserts some extra `\tabcolsep` spaces and so add three lines to compensate:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter

    \def\CT@@do@color{%
      \global\let\CT@do@color\relax
            \@tempdima\wd\z@
            \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimb
            \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimc
    \advance\@tempdimb\tabcolsep
    \advance\@tempdimc\tabcolsep
    \advance\@tempdima2\tabcolsep
            \kern-\@tempdimb
            \leaders\vrule
    %^^A                     \@height\p@\@depth\p@
                    \hskip\@tempdima\@plus  1fill
            \kern-\@tempdimc
            \hskip-\wd\z@ \@plus -1fill }
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ |c|l|l| } \hline
    \rowcolor{red} A    & B     & C     \\ \hline
    Hello World         & other     & \cellcolor{blue}stuff\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Well played David, first prize to you. I'm gonna resign myself to the fact that these little tweaks will be out of my reach for quite some time.

Comment: @sven such tweaks are easier if you've written the package and had something to do with the class that's in conflict.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you wrap up the `tabular` environment into `ruledtabular` one that adds nice starting and opening double horizontal bars.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is still present with the class `revtex4.2` (v. 4.2e).

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (similar to `{tabular}` of `array`), you have directly the output you want. In fact, the output is better than with the class `article` because the rules won't seem to vanish in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom (as in the picture of the OP).

```
 \documentclass{revtex4-2}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{NiceTabular}{ |c|l|l| }[colortbl-like] \hline
 \rowcolor{red} A    & B     & C     \\ \hline
 Hello World         & other     & \cellcolor{blue}stuff\\ \hline
 \end{NiceTabular}
 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]