# A problem with revtex4 and colortbl

Tags: errors, revtex, colortbl

I never ran into the following problem before, where every time I tried to use matrices, LaTeX generated an error;

```
!undefined control sequence.
```

I was very puzzled as to how does this error come about. Did I use something that I should not be using?

```
\documentclass{revtex4} 
\usepackage{amsmath,colortbl} 
\begin{document}
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `colortbl` package; your example works without it. I'm not yet sure why this is though.

Comment: Your code is far from being minimal. You should remove packages one by one in order to isolate the problem. If you do that, you end up with this Minimal non-Working Example: `\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$\end{document}`

Comment: In other news: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?lq=1

Comment: @IanThompson what a thing to say:-) Try changing revtex4 to article and you'll see it works:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- it's Friday and I've had a few beers. Otherwise I would have known that the blame lay elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I strip out most of the custom commands and package loading, then this is what I’m left with which still shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{revtex4}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to arise as a conflict between the `revtex4` class and the `colortbl` package. Removing either one (either not loading `colortbl`, or using the `article` class) makes the problem go away.

There’s an answer [by David Carlisle (who wrote `colortbl`) involving these two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102665/revtex4-1-and-colortbl-doesnt-fill-cells) which is using the `revtex4-1` class. I assume this is a similar but slightly newer version of `revtex4`. I find that using that makes the problem go away, so I’d recommend using that class if you can.

If not, wait until somebody who knows these packages/classes better to explain where the conflict lies, and what a suitable workaround might be.

Comment: I think that revtex4-1 is intended as a replacement for all uses of revtex4, and it fixes this so I think that's the full answer.