# Revtex4-2 tabular Table with alternating colors rows formatting issues

Tags: tables, revtex, colortbl

### Description of issue

I would like to make a table like the following in a LaTeX document that uses `revtex4-2` as its document class:
[image: desired table]

However, the table that I generate with LaTeX has a bunch of white columns that are undesired:
[image: revtex4-2 table]

Strangely, these white columns are not present when I use `article` as my document class:
[image: regular-article table]

### LaTeX code:

```latex
\documentclass[aps, twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
% \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{ll|c|cc|c|c|ccc|c}
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} &
  \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Col3} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} &
  AA &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}BB} &
  CC &
  DD &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}EE} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Col1} &
  \multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Col2} &
   &
  b.1 &
  b.2 &
   &
   &
  e.1 &
  e.2 &
  e.3 &
  \multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Col4} \\ \hline
dat1 & 111 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 &      & 1.00 &  & 1.00 &      & 111111.00  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
dat2 & 222 & 0.00 &      & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.50 &  & 1.00 & 1.00 & 222222.00  \\
dat3 & 333 & 0.00 &      &      &      &      &  &      &      & 333333.00  \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
dat4 & 444 & 0.00 &      &      &      &      &  &      &      & 4444444.00
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this StackExchange discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102665/revtex4-1-and-colortbl-doesnt-fill-cells), `nicematrix` does the job!

[image: nicematrix-table]

```latex
\documentclass[aps, twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}ll|c|cc|c|c|ccc|c@{}}
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{gray!10}{1-3}
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}
\Body
% \toprule
     &      & \Block{1-8}{Col3} &                 &          &      &      &                  &       &       &            \\  
     &      &                   & \Block{1-2}{BB} &          &      &      & \Block{1-3}{EE}  &       &       &            \\  
Col1 & Col1 & AA                & b.1  & b.2                 & CC   & DD   & e.1              & e.2   & e.3   & Col4       \\  
\midrule                                                                                                                       
dat1 & 111  & 0.00              & 1.00            & 1.00     &      & 1.00 &                  & 1.00  &       & 111111.00  \\  
dat2 & 222  & 0.00              &                 & 1.00     & 1.00 & 0.50 &                  & 1.00  & 1.00  & 222222.00  \\  
dat3 & 333  & 0.00              &                 &          &      &      &                  &       &       & 333333.00  \\  
dat4 & 444  & 0.00              &                 &          &      &      &                  &       &       & 444444.00  \\   
% \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of the new LaTeX 3 `tabularray` package also gives desired result already after one compilation. In MWE below is considered the package Version 2021K (2021-06-05):

```
\documentclass[aps, twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularray}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {ll|c|cc|c|c|ccc|c},
             colsep=4pt,
             row{odd} = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2}   = {bg=gray!30},      
             rowsep=1pt,
            }    
\multirow{3}{*}{Col1}
    &   \multirow{3}{*}{Col2}
        & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Col3}                     & \multirow{3}{*}{Col4} \\
    &   & AA & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BB}   & CC  & DD  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{EE} & \\
    &   &   & b.1 & b.2 &   &   & e.1   & e.2 & e.3 &                           \\
    \hline
dat1 & 111 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 &      & 1.00 &     & 1.00 &      & 111111.00   \\
dat2 & 222 & 0.00 &      & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.50 &     & 1.00 & 1.00 & 222222.00   \\
dat3 & 333 & 0.00 &      &      &      &      &     &      &      & 333333.00   \\
%
dat4 & 444 & 0.00 &      &      &      &      &     &      &      & 4444444.00
\end{tblr}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]