Cell color in table does not fill whole cell
I have a table like this:
\documentclass[aps,prc,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl, multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|ll|}
\hline
                    &                     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{C}                              \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{A} & \multirow{-2}{*}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{C1}                        & C2 \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FE0000} 
t                   & e                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}x} & t  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}

which gives the output:

What I want is simple: I want the colored cells to be colored entirely, without white borders. I have tried messing around cellcolor and rowcolor commands but to no avail.
Anyone has a solution?
Kind regards.

Have a look at the tabularray package. It makes it easy to colour cells.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

If I copy your code snippet and place it into a reasonable document structure (that is putting \documentclass{article} \usepackage{xcolor, colortbl, multirow} \begin{document} before and \end{document} after the code), I do not get the output you show, but the red background fills the cells completely. So, without a complete MWE from your side, it is just guesswork what goes wrong here.

you need to show an example of your issue, the white spaces are due to code you have not shown, so it is hard to help, please always show a complete document

unrelated but note that \begin{table}[] means "do not allow the table anywhere" latex would have warned about that [] and changed it to allow the table to be placed. Use \begin{table} not \begin{table}[]

Apologies for the wrong format. It is my first time asking here. I edited the initial post including a compilable document that shows the problem.

Seems to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102665/47927 now
